# Limit functionality in WildCats

Tags: packages

Does the latest version of the [WildCats](https://wildcatsformma.wordpress.com/) (diagrammatic Category Theory) package support the calculation of limits (the associated tutorial section is empty)?

If so, can anyone point me to a simple example of their use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am the developer of WildCats. A new version with some "limit" functionality and a palette is almost ready and should be available soon (in a few weeks at most). In the meantime your feedback and suggestions are always appreciated.

Comment: thanks, I look forward to the forthcoming release.

Comment: is there an updated ETA on this functionality?

Comment: @user217281728  it's not clear to me what you mean by updated ETA

Comment: ETA = estimated time of arrival, i.e. due date. Thanks and best wishes.

Comment: @user217281728 ETA is end of February, perhaps earlier

Comment: I have installed the WildCats with Mathematica 12, but unfortunately none of the tutorials work. Is there any update to the package?

Comment: @Stephan I have not tried WildCats with MMA 12 yet. Did you have problems with older versions?In what sense the tutorials do not work?